# MySQL- query for encrypted values in GROUP_CONCAT using MAX

Tags: mysql, sql, encryption

I have got error while fetching encrypted values in
 `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT CONCAT('MAX(IF`
tag, actually i m trying to get pivot values for tables, i have two tables with thousands of row values but for simplicity i have given some in short below-

individual_data table as,

```
-----------------------------------
|ID         |fieldname  |answertext|
-----------------------------------
|30101      |state      |0         |
-----------------------------------
|30101      |Number |4         |
-----------------------------------
|30101      |Name       |Rajbanshi |
-----------------------------------
|30101      |Main       |RAJBANSHI |
-----------------------------------
|30101      |Surname    |RAJBANSHI |
-----------------------------------
|30201      |state      |0         |
-----------------------------------
|30201      |Number     |4         |
-----------------------------------
|30201      |Name       |Pawar     |
-----------------------------------
|30201      |Main       |Ramesh    |
-----------------------------------
|30201      |Surname    |Pawar     |
-----------------------------------
```

***Note**- in this table 'aswertext' field is encrypted but for sake of clarity i have given actual values and i need this values to be appear in output...

and sms_household table as,

```
-------------------------
|HHID   |sampletype |urid|
-------------------------
|30100  |3          |3008|
-------------------------
|30200  |4          |3005|
-------------------------
```

and want desired result as,

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|ID     |state  |Number |Name       |Main       |Surname    |sampletype |urid |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|30101  |0      |4      |Rajbanshi  |RAJBANSHI  |RAJBANSHI  |3          |3008 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|30201  |0      |4      |Pawar      |Ramesh     |Pawar      |4          |3005 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

for the same i have written the query like,

```
SET @@group_concat_max_len = 3000;
SET @sql = NULL;
SELECT 
GROUP CONCAT (DISTINCT 
CONCAT(
'MAX(IF(I.fieldname = ''',
fieldname, 
''', convert(aes_decrypt(answertext,'xyz')USING utf8), NULL)) AS ',
fieldname
)
) INTO @sql
FROM individual_data;

SET @sql = CONCAT('SELECT I.ID, H.sampletype, H.urid', @sql,
'FROM individual_data I inner join sms_household H on H.hhid = concat'(left(I.ID,4),'0')' and H.hhid like '30%' and H.urid like '30%' GROUP BY I.prim_key');

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;`
```

but i got syntax error msg in the line `convert(aes_decrypt(answertext,'basbas')USING utf8), NULL)) AS '.....

i am not getting what is wrong with this code..!!

Comment: Didn't I see something very similar here just an hour ago?

Comment: ya.... i deleted previous one due to some wrong texts....so plz continue with this question....

Answer (score 0):

Your code is very hard to follow.  At the very least you have misspellings in `group_concat()` and insufficient quoting around `'xyz'`.

These types of statements are difficult to construct.  I like to use a method with `replace()` rather than with `concat()`.  This makes it clearer to see the structure of the final expression.

So, something like this:

```
set @exp = 'max(case when i.fieldname = ''@f''
                     then convert(aes_decrypt(@a, ''xyz'') USING utf8)
                end) as @f'

select group_concat(distinct replace(replace(@exp, '@f', fieldname
                                            ), '@a', answertext
                                    )
                   ) INTO @sql
FROM individual_data;
```

I'm not 100% sure if that is your intention, but this should set you down a better path.